# Firefox context menu opening delayed by about 5 seconds

Tags: unity, firefox, 17.04, thunderbird

I was using my computer a couple of days ago with no issues, shutdown the computer for the night, then the next day there is a delay for the context menu to show up after right clicking in both Firefox and Thunderbird.

Aside from installing a few updates I have not made any changes to the computer since the day before & I have no issue with context menus in other browsers or the OS.

The hardware a Dell Optiplex 790 with an i5-2400 quad core, 12 Gb ram running Ubuntu 17.04 64bit.

**The symptoms:**

- The right click context menu takes approx 5 to 8 sec to show up.
- Drop down menus on web pages & in settings behave the same.
- Occasionally the FF window will darken for a second or two then return to normal.
- When an option on the context menu is clicked it is taking about 3 sec to go through.

**Fixes tried:**

- New Profile.
- Safe Mode.
- Disabling Hardware Acceleration.
- Complete removal of FF & TB as well as their folders.
- Downgrading to FF version 50.
- Checked on another computer (this one is running Lubuntu, & does not show the issue).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has appeared to have been fixed somehow, the only things that have changed is more updates have been installed and the removal and reinstall of the Nvidia drivers (got a GT-710 card).

My guess is that the Nvidia drivers were not playing nice with my old graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

After years of annoyance with this issue, I finally found the problem by accident: the sound server is started when the first right click occurs. I had system logs opened at the same time, I could see a ton of things appearing at this moment.

```
Feb 16 12:44:03 host systemd[362]: Starting Sound Service...
[ a lot of things truncated ]
Feb 16 12:44:05 host systemd[362]: Started Sound Service.
```

So maybe adding the sound service in the automatic start will fix the issue.

For me, disabling hardware acceleration did not help. I hope this helps others in the same situation. Cheers